# Pass UIButton by reference

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, pass-by-reference

I'm trying to create a "helper class" to animate UI elements but I did not succeed. I should say I'm still a beginner about iOS programming and I like to do anything programmatically.

What I'm doing is:

```
 Animator *anim;
 myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect]; 
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(addToFav) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[myButton setTitle:@"+" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:23]];
[myButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
[myButton setFrame:CGRectMake(screenWidth * 0.9 - (SizeX / 2), screenHeight * 0.2285 - (SizeY / 2), X, Y)];
[self.view addSubview: myButton];
[anim moveButton:&myButton alongX:-100 alongY:200 withTime:1.5];
```

and this is

Animator.h

```
@interface Animator : NSObject

-(void)moveButton:(UIButton*)button alongX:(int)x alongY:(int)y withTime:(float)time;
-(void)scaleButton:(UIButton*)button width:(float)width height:(float)height withTime:(float)time;

@end
```

Animator.m

```
@implementation Animator

-(void)moveButton:(UIButton*)button alongX:(int)x alongY:(int)y withTime:(float)time
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:time];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(button.frame.origin.x + x, button.frame.origin.y + y, button.frame.size.width, button.frame.size.height)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(void)scaleButton:(UIButton*)button width:(float)width height:(float)height withTime:(float)time
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:time];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(button.frame.origin.x, button.frame.origin.y, button.frame.size.width * width, button.frame.size.height * height)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

@end
```

The compiler tells it's not possible to pass the address of UIButton because of ARC, which I wouldn't want to disable and I don't even know how much of an help it would be to disable ARC.

Is there any way to pass the UIButton by reference?

Test code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Animator.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
    UIButton* myButton;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib

    myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(move) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [myButton setTitle:@"+" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [myButton setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:23]];
    [myButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    [myButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    [self.view addSubview: myButton];

}
-(void)move
{
    Animator *anim;
    [anim moveButton:myButton alongX:-100 alongY:200 withTime:1.5];


    /*[UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 animations:^{ // animate
        myButton.frame = CGRectOffset(myButton.frame, 0, 200); // set new frame but with specified offset
    }];*/
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: The answer below by @Duc is correct. Your 'button' IS a pointer and you need to use it directly. However, in addition, i would like to mention that it will be better to declare your 'helper' methods as class methods instead of instance method (`+(void)moveButton:`).Your helper class need never be instantiated and you can directly use them like `[Animator moveButton:myButton`.

Comment: You're correct, thanks for the tip
EDIT: By declaring the methods as class methods the animation works! Thanks a lot lukya! If you could answer the question I'll select yours as the correct answer. Thanks to everybody else as well for the help!

Comment: You did not initialize animator. Thats why your Code didnt work. The Code you provided was almost correct. But declaring your methods as class methods is definetly the better style.

Comment: GianlucaBS, the problem with your code was indeed what @Duc mentioned - you did not initialise your animator. He has updated his answer to fix your issue. Declaring the methods as class method was merely a design improvement suggestion. I think you should accept Duc's answer.

Comment: Also, whether class or instance methods, your button should be passed without the `&`. Your question title asks about passing by reference which is also answered correctly by @Duc ... the button object IS A POINTER.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
[anim moveButton:myButton alongX:-100 alongY:200 withTime:1.5]; // no asterisk!
```

Notice that myButton which I believe you have initialized like that:

```
UIButton *myButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
```

is **A POINTER** not the object itself. So using &myButton means: Get the address of the pointer! But as you see you don't need the address of the pointer but of the button. Just pass myButton as it is already a pointer to myButton.

**Another Approach**

Here I have s simple code snippet which should work for you. If not, the problem lies somewhere else.

```
-(void)moveButton:(UIButton*)button alongX:(int)x alongY:(int)y withTime:(float)time 
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:time animations:^{ // animate
        button.frame = CGRectOffset(button.frame, x, y); // set new frame but with specified offset
    }];
}
```

*Just a tip: Change the method signature to this*

```
-(void)moveButton:(UIButton*)button alongX:(CGFloat)x alongY:(CGFloat)y withTime:(CGFloat)time;
-(void)scaleButton:(UIButton*)button width:(CGFloat)width height:(CGFloat)height withTime:(CGFloat)time;
```

**Hopefully this is your solution :)**

```
Animator *anim = [[Animator alloc] init];
[anim moveButton:myButton alongX:-100 alongY:200 withTime:1.5];
```

Comment: I tried that way but the button doesn't move. The button is initialised like this : myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

Comment: You did not set the frame of your button. So try this before you start animating: `myButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 100.0);`

Answer (score 0):

For the example you've provided I don't think you actually need to pass the button by reference. The methods on `Animator` take a pointer to a `UIButton` and `myButton` matches that. You only need to pass an object by reference if you want to reassign the pointer, `Animator` does not currently do this.

I think you simply need to change `moveButton:&myButton` to `moveButton:myButton`.

That being said, if you ever *did* want to pass a pointer by reference (commonly done with `NSError` out params), you need to change the signature to use a double pointer and pass in using the `&` operator as you've done.

The signature for `NSFileManager`'s `remoteItemAtURL:error:` method serves as an example.

```
NSError *error = nil;
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:url error:&error];

// error could now be pointing to something other than nil
```

(See https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/removeItemAtURL:error:)